# How can i access cross-platform(android/iOS) bluetooth detection for flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, cross-platform, multipeer-connectivity, google-nearby-connections

Newbie here. I am trying to make a hybrid mobile app in flutter that will detect nearby Bluetooth devices based on some unique ID. I want to read that unique ID from the endpoint and compare it onto the DBMS. I want this for both android as well as iOS.

For reference following code is from nearby_connections plugin but is only for android. https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections

```
    bool a = await Nearby().startDiscovery(loggedInUser.email, strategy,
    onEndpointFound: (id, name, serviceId) async {
    print('I saw id:$id with name:$name');
```

Answer (score 1):

This flutter package seems compatible with Android and iOS, mayb you can try it : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections

Comment: Does it work from ios to android?

Comment: It's written that it's compatible for both

Comment: Yeah I see that Ive sent it to my colleague who has an iOS, but if its using 2 different technologies on different platforms then will it still connect?